# Scrollable vertical navigation bar based on content

Tags: html, css

I have here a vertical navigation bar. After some help, it still looks a bit weird. The flexbox idea is good, but the whole navigation is already in a flexbox. So it doesn't completely look now how it should. Why does the text wrap? And why is there text outside the box?

Here is the code:

```css
.content {
display: flex;
}

.column {
height: 100vh;
background: darkgrey;
}

.column_content {
overflow-y: scroll;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
}

nav {
border-left: 2px solid black;
-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}

nav ul {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
}

nav ul li {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

<div class="column">
<div class="column_content">
Text
</div>
</div>

<nav class="column">
<div class="column_content">
<ul>
<li>Link eins</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
<li>Link</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>

</div>
```

Thanks for help! <3

Comment: You can but what should happen when you scroll to the last item of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex-direction: row;` for the list and this will keep the list always on scroll.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*height: 800vh;*/
}

nav {
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  background: darkgrey;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  /* use this */
  flex-direction: row;
  /* use this */
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I've tried it. My navigation was/is already in a flexbox and it doesn't work with your idea how it should ...

Comment: I don't understand based on the code you shared and the snippet it works as you asked for.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I tried it for what I want to do and realized that there is a difference. Just updated my question. Sorry for that!

Comment: Hmmm.. in that case you can give a min-height and make the overflow:auto; by doing this you won't be restricting this with any height constraint and the scroll can go forever, would like to see that?

Comment: Hm. I think I am okay so far. I have another idea now. But your code definitely helps me with that. Thaaank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex` on the `<ul>` element to display the `<li>` elements in one row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  background: darkgrey;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

nav {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ul {
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  /* height: 800vh; */
  display: flex; /* Use Flexbox */
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Text</p>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much! I've tried it. My navigation was/is already in a flexbox and it doesn't work with your idea how it should ...